# Why is the second part of $H = -p \log_2(p) - (1-p)\log_2(1 - p)$ positive after $\frac{dH}{dp}$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, logarithms

My problem is the following:

$$H = -p \log_2(p) - (1-p)\log_2(1 - p)$$
$$\frac{dH}{dp} = -\log_2(p) - \frac{p}{p \ln(2)} + \log_2(1-p) + \frac{1-p}{(1-p)\ln(2)}$$

$p$ is the probability of an event, whereas $1-p$ represents the opposite probability. The product rule states that $f(x) + g(x) \mapsto f'(x) * g(x) + f(x) * g'(x)$. The derivation of $\log_b(x)$ is $\frac{1}{x \ln(b)}$.

Differentiating the first part, $-p \log_2(p)$, makes sens to me. But when it comes to differentiating the second part, $- (1-p)\log_2(1 - p)$, I don’t get it. Why is the factor positive **two** times?

Comment: Because of the negative signs in front of the $p$s. When you differentiate $(1-p)$, you get $(-1)$, and when you differentiate $\log_2(1-p)$, you get $-\frac{1}{(1-p)\ln 2}$ (apply chain rule with $1-p$ the inner function).

Comment: But the second part of the second part should be $-(1-p) * \frac{1}{(1-p) \ln(2)}$ and not $+(1-p) * \frac{1}{(1-p) \ln(2)}$. The differentiation of the first part of the second part is positive because the differentiation of $(1-p)$ becomes positive. But according to the product rule, $(1-p)$ isn’t differentiated in the second part of the second part anymore. Thus, $-$ should endure, shouldn’t it?

Comment: Did you read my comment? If differentiating $(1-p)\log_2(1-p)$ gives you two minus signs, then differentiating  $-(1-p)\log_2(1-p)$ gives you two plus signs. Tell me which part of my first comment you don't understand.

Comment: You edited your comment. I only saw the sentence “Because of the negative signs in front of the $p$s.” and the rest wasn’t there yet. But now I get it. Thanks.